# Azure function not starting even manually (no error message)

Tags: azure, cron, azure-functions

I created a time-triggered function. In order to create the CRON string (start every morning at 01:00) I used a web service. The function.json contained the following trig instructions:

```
"type" : "timerTrigger",
"name" : "timer",
"direction" : "in",
"schedule" : "0 0 1 ? * * *"
```

The function didn't start, no error given even if launched manually.

Taking more attention, the "schedule" string was underlined, so I changed it by using another web service, that gave me a different CRON string (for the same time).
It didn't solve, and anyway I was running the function manually clicking on "play" button...

Where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, the error was where I noticed it; the format for CRON strings in Azure must have 6 parts, or at least the following example (created by changing the examples given in the Azure documentation) is solving the issue:

```
"schedule" : "0 0 1 * * *"
```

Another colleague had the same problem... it's very easy to get services that easily create cron strings...

Hopefully this will save time to other people.